# Why does my Honda Civic 2016 turbo keep failing

Tags: honda, civic, turbocharger, warning-light

3 mechanic said its the turbo. I have now replaced it 4x and only get 6 months at most before the tin can dragging sound comes back when i press gas then i lose power where the car will buck and not go over 7 mph but it all starts with a simple scraping sound when i press on the gas. the sound comes from front passenger side in front end. when i take my foot off the gas the noise goes away. After driving it like that it eventually goes away and thats when all dummy lights come on and power is reduced

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! My thinking is you have a lack of oil going to the turbo, which wears it out over time. Is your turbo OEM or aftermarket? I'm assuming you have the 1.5L 4-cylinder engine? Also, if the dummy lights are showing up, have you checked to see what codes may be stored? If so, what are those codes.

Comment: By any chance, do you live very close to an interstate highway and have a habit of merging into high speed traffic just a minute or two after starting your car after a long cold Wisconsin night? And maybe you use 10W-40 oil or a thick, honey-like oil treatment? If so, oil starvation is killing your turbos. More on this in a formal answer if you reply in the affirmative.

Comment: First 3 were honda turbos las one was after market. And no I let my car warm up and only travel short distances. I do not know what oil is used honda changes the oil. and yes the codes said it culd be multiple things and all those parts were done as well

Comment: how do i reply in the affirmative

Comment: @DominiqueFredrickson You replied in the negative, i.e., you said no, you don't start it then immediately jump on the highway, and we'll assume that Honda is using the right oil and no additive. So I have nothing further to say about oil starvation being caused by these two no-no's. I suggest you have an oil pressure test using a mechanical gauge to rule out low oil pressure as a cause of turbo failure. To direct your comment to a particular person, begin the comment with "@" and the person's name as you see on this message.